# Perform a t-test in multiple regression matrix

Tags: regression, t-test, covariance-matrix

I have the following matrices: $$ X'X $$ $$X'y$$$$ y'y $$

I know that the B matrix can be computed as follows : $$ B = (X'X)^{-1}X'y $$

If I want to perform a t test for a specific B, say $$B_{1}$$, I know that I must follow the formula : $$ t = \frac{B_{1} - B_{0}}{\textrm{se}(B_{1})} $$

However, if I only have the 3 aforementioned matrices, how can I compute the standard error of a given $B?$

Answer (score 0):

If $\epsilon$ designate your residuals, estimator variance matrix is given by $Var(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}, \sigma^2 = Var(\epsilon)$ in my class notes but I can't demonstrate it so can't be a 100% sure.

EDIT : this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88461/derive-variance-of-regression-coefficient-in-simple-linear-regression) gives (and proves) $Var(\beta_1) = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum\limits_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$ so I guess my notes are still good enough :)

Comment: Even I am trying to get my head around this. From what I understand, to obtain 'e' you need Y and predicted Y matrices (which are not there). I guess there is some way you can get those from y'y.

Comment: How can you not have $\hat{Y}$ if you have $X$ and $\beta$ ? Because I would say that you can not derive estimators variance without some kind of information on the residuals.

Comment: according to the question only 3 matrices are available: X'X, X'y and y'y. Matrix X is not there.

Comment: Is that a self-study case ?

Comment: homework case rather ;)

Comment: So there must be a solution, but I can't find any reference in which $\hat{Y}$ is not needed for $Var(\beta)$ to be computed