# Easiest way to derive standard error of linear regression model slope directly?

Tags: regression, standard-error

Assume that we want to derive the standard error of $\beta_2$ in: 
$$y=\beta_1 + \beta_2x_2 +u$$

$u$ iid with mean $0$ variance $\sigma ^2$. The way I know how to do it, is convert it in matrix form, $$y=X\beta +u$$

then simply derive the variance of the OLS estimator of $\beta$ and take the lower right value of that matrix.

But surely there is a way to do this directly, without converting it in matrix form. **What is the way to do this with a low amount of algebraic steps?**

Comment: Are you asking about a mathematical derivation or for steps to simply calculate?

Comment: @Alexis, I'm not sure what the difference is? Let's say a mathematical derivation.

Comment: So I would call this a way to calculate: $s^{2}_{\beta_{2}}= \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\varepsilon_{i}^{2}}}{n-2}}}{s_{x}\sqrt{n-1}}\right)^{2}$, where $\varepsilon = \left[y_{i} - \left(\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}x_{i}\right)\right]$, but I would not call it a mathematical derivation (although it is mathematically derived). :)

Comment: @Alexis, ah ok. No that's the result I'm looking to find out how to derive quickly :P so yes I mean a derivation.

Comment: So "calculate" always refers to the part where you plug in the numbers and get an actual number as a result? I tend to use "calculate" and "derive" interchangeably, but maybe that's wrong.

Comment: Related: [Derive Variance of regression coefficient in simple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88461/derive-variance-of-regression-coefficient-in-simple-linear-regression?rq=1)