# Found an expression I haven't encountered before

Tags: regression, standard-error

I was reading the book *an introduction to statistical learning with R*
(http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/data.html), and came across this expression that I haven't seen before. Can anyone tell me what this means:

$$
{\bar x^{2} \over \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar x)^2}
$$

The full equation (where I saw it is:)
$$
SE(\hat \beta)^2 = \sigma^2 [{1 \over n} + {\bar x^{2} \over \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - \bar x)^2}]
$$

FYI. this is the equation for calculating the standard error of the coefficients of linear regression (ML).

Comment: The bottom term is variance, but why is it being divided by mean squared?

Comment: What is exactly your doubt? Do you think there is something wrong about it?

Comment: I wanted to know what this term means. As stated above, I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is a formula for the standard estimation error for a given parameter $\beta$ in terms of the sample mean, the observations.

$\sigma$ stands for the standard deviation of the errors $\epsilon$, assuming a model of the form $y=\beta + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$

$\epsilon$ is assumed to follow a normal distribution $N(0, \sigma^2)$

The part you highlight is just the square of the sample mean divided by $n*Var(x)$

Comment: by 'it,' you mean the expression, right?

Comment: Sure! I mean "the expression"

Answer (score 0):

This is an expression that most statistics students are taught to derive when learning linear regression. I'm not necessarily sure that that term has a great interpretation, it's just derived. I would take a look at this thread to see how this term pops up: [Derive Variance of regression coefficient in simple linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88461/derive-variance-of-regression-coefficient-in-simple-linear-regression)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't done statistics at school yet, self-taught till now so that's probably why I didn't know.